# error while trying to start new intent

Tags: android

I would just like to check for data, using log cat.
So when I click on a button, it will go to another activity and it will log the data in the log cat.
however,
it gave me a force close.

I'm trying to do a simple checking,nothing else.

Can someone guide me along?
Thanks

logcat:

```
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fuellogproject/com.example.fuellogproject.summary}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at com.example.fuellogproject.summary.onCreate(summary.java:39)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
01-27 21:38:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(26992):    ... 11 more
```

This is my code

```
public class summary extends Activity {
    TextView month;
    TextView avgPrice;
    TextView exFuel;
    TextView avgFC;
    Button doneButton;
    Button exitButton;
       private String bundleID;
       private String bundleDate;
        private String bundlePrice;
        private String bundlePump;
        private String bundleCost;
        private String bundleOdometer;
        private String bundlePreOdometer;

        private String bundleFcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summary);
        month = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.month);
        avgPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showavfPriceTV);
        exFuel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showexFuelTV);
        avgFC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showavgFCTV);
        doneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneBTN);
        exitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exitBTN);

        Bundle takeBundledData = getIntent().getExtras();
        // First we need to get the bundle data that pass from the updateAnddelete
                    bundleID = takeBundledData.getString("clickedID");
                    bundleDate = takeBundledData.getString("clickedDate");
                    bundlePrice = takeBundledData.getString("clickedPrice");
                    bundlePump = takeBundledData.getString("clickedPump");
                    bundleCost = takeBundledData.getString("clickedCost");
                    bundleOdometer = takeBundledData.getString("clickedOdometer");
                    bundlePreOdometer = takeBundledData.getString("clickedpreOdometer");
                    bundleFcon = takeBundledData.getString("clickedFCon");
                    Log.d("Bundle","bundle : "+ takeBundledData);

    }

}
```

update.java

```
    private ArrayList<fuelLogPojo> pojoArrayList;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_all);

    // Initialize UI components
    dateListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.allListView);
    dateListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBTN);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    summaryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.summaryBTN);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    /*
     * pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<fuelLogPojo>();
     * 
     * // For the third argument, we need a List that contains Strings. //We
     * decided to display undergraduates names on the ListView. //Therefore
     * we need to create List that contains undergraduates names
     * LogListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     * android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
     * 
     * dateListView.setAdapter(LogListAdapter);
     */

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent mainAct = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainAct);
}






// To create a List that contains undergraduate names, we have to read the
// SQLite database
// We are going to do it in the separate method
public List<String> populateList() {

    // We have to return a List which contains only String values. Lets
    // create a List first
    List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // First we need to make contact with the database we have created using
    // the DbHelper class
    AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

    // Then we need to get a readable database
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

    // We need a a guy to read the database query. Cursor interface will do
    // it for us
    // (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[]
    // selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(
            AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    // Above given query, read all the columns and fields of the table

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Cursor object read all the fields. So we make sure to check it will
    // not miss any by looping through a while loop
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // In one loop, cursor read one undergraduate all details
        // Assume, we also need to see all the details of each and every
        // undergraduate
        // What we have to do is in each loop, read all the values, pass
        // them to the POJO class
        // and create a ArrayList of undergraduates
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ROWID));
        Log.d("ViewAll","id : "+id);
        String date = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_DATE));
        String price = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PRICE));
        String pump = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_FUEL));
        String cost = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_COST));
        String odm = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ODM));
        String preodm = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PREODM));
        String fcon = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_CON));

        // Finish reading one raw, now we have to pass them to the POJO
        fuelLogPojo logPojoClass = new fuelLogPojo();
        logPojoClass.setid(id);
        logPojoClass.setdate(date);
        logPojoClass.setprice(price);
        logPojoClass.setpump(pump);
        logPojoClass.setcost(cost);
        logPojoClass.setodometer(odm);
        logPojoClass.setpreodometer(preodm);

        logPojoClass.setfcon(fcon);
        // Lets pass that POJO to our ArrayList which contains
        // undergraduates as type
        pojoArrayList.add(logPojoClass);

        // But we need a List of String to display in the ListView also.
        // That is why we create "uGraduateNamesList"
        dateList.add(date);
    }
    // If you don't close the database, you will get an error
    sqliteDatabase.close();

    return dateList;
}

@Override
public void startManagingCursor(Cursor c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

        super.startManagingCursor(c);

    }
}

// If you don't write the following code, you wont be able to see what you
// have just insert to the database
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<fuelLogPojo>();

    LogListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    dateListView.setAdapter(LogListAdapter);

}

/*
 * protected void onStart() { super.onStart(); // pojoArrayList = new
 * ArrayList<fuelLogPojo>(); LogListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
 * android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
 * dateListView.setAdapter(LogListAdapter); }
 */

// On ListView you just see the name of the undergraduate, not any other
// details
// Here we provide the solution to that. When the user click on a list item,
// he will redirect to a page where
// he can see all the details of the undergraduate
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on :" + arg2,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // We want to redirect to another Activity when the user click an item
    // on the ListView
    Intent changesAct = new Intent(this, updateAnddelete.class);

    // We have to identify what object, does the user clicked, because we
    // are going to pass only clicked object details to the next activity
    // What we are going to do is, get the ID of the clicked item and get
    // the values from the ArrayList which has
    // same array id.
    fuelLogPojo clickedObject = pojoArrayList.get(arg2);

    // We have to bundle the data, which we want to pass to the other
    // activity from this activity
    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("clickedID", clickedObject.getid());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedDate", clickedObject.getdate());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedPrice", clickedObject.getprice());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedPump", clickedObject.getpump());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedCost", clickedObject.getcost());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedOdometer", clickedObject.getodometer());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedpreOdometer",
            clickedObject.getpreodometer());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedFCon", clickedObject.getfcon());
    Log.i("FuelLog", "dataBundle " + dataBundle);
    // Attach the bundled data to the intent
    changesAct.putExtras(dataBundle);

    // Start the Activity
    startActivity(changesAct);

}

public void summaryClick(View v) {
    Intent summary = new Intent(this, summary.class);
    startActivity(summary);
}
```

}

Comment: com.example.fuellogproject.summary.onCreate(summary.java:39) what is there at this line ?

Comment: bundleID = takeBundledData.getString("clickedID");

Comment: @Chloe cross check the key in the other activity

Comment: it's probably a typo in one of your bundles, you're getting a nullpointerexception at line 39 in onCreate, sidenote: your class should be named Summary, not summary.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though your `takedBundledData` Bundle is null.

You can confirm this by moving the statement:

```
Log.d("Bundle","bundle : "+ takeBundledData);
```

just before

```
bundleID = takeBundledData.getString("clickedID");
```

Check that you're actually sending the bundle with the Intent from the calling activity.

**UPDATE**

When you start the summary activity, you are not sending any data with the intent:

```
public void summaryClick(View v) {
    Intent summary = new Intent(this, summary.class);
     //NO DATA
    startActivity(summary);
}
```

But when you start the update activity, you are passing data:

```
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    //DATA ADDED HERE
    dataBundle.putString("clickedID", clickedObject.getid());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedDate", clickedObject.getdate());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedPrice", clickedObject.getprice());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedPump", clickedObject.getpump());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedCost", clickedObject.getcost());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedOdometer", clickedObject.getodometer());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedpreOdometer",
            clickedObject.getpreodometer());
    dataBundle.putString("clickedFCon", clickedObject.getfcon());
    Log.i("FuelLog", "dataBundle " + dataBundle);
    // Attach the bundled data to the intent
    changesAct.putExtras(dataBundle);

    // Start the Activity
    startActivity(changesAct);
```

So pass data to the summary activity the same way you passed it to the Update activity.

Comment: why my bundle is null, i just copy and paste the same bundle in my update where I retrieve it from listview

Comment: Please paste your startActivity code with your question, and then we can point out where you went wrong